# How to fetch a data from an API in MERN stack web application project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am building a library management system using MERN Stack, where the ISBN number is fetched from free Google Book API. But I am confused about how to fetch an API to my application.

Comment: Can you please share some code you have tried so far.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you have worked out something'

Comment: use axios lib for handling api in react...

Comment: I just want to know the method/idea to fetch data from an API either using ReactJS or Node.js. It would be really helpful if you add the codes as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API implemented by browsers or [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for using with ReactJS (or any frontend code for that matter)

With `nodejs` you can use pacakages like `request, request-promise, node-fetch, axios` in similar fashion.

An example using `request` library available for `nodejs`

```
request
  .get('http://google.com/img.png' // api url)
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
    // save the image somewhere, or render to webpage
  })
  .pipe(request.put('http://yoursite.com/img.png'))
```